# Problems with the footers in the plain pages with srcbook

Tags: graphics, fancyhdr, scrbook, footer

```
\documentclass[12pt, titlepage,twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage[a4paper, inner = 37.5 mm, outer = 17.5mm, top = 35mm, bottom = 35mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\spacing{1.3}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{babel,blindtext}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lmodern,textcomp}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhf[OF]{\cfoot{}}
\fancyhf[EF]{\cfoot{}}
\fancyhf[REF,LOF]{\includegraphics[width = 5.11cm, height=1.35cm]{Image.png}}
\fancyhf[LEF,ROF]{\foot{\thepage}}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\chapter{Abstract}
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{introduction}

\end{document}
```

When I compile, there are problems with the lines of Chapters and Table of contents.

Answer (score 2):

The correct `fancyhdr` syntax would be

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhf[REF,LOF]{\includegraphics[width = 5.11cm, height=1.35cm]{example-image}}
\fancyhf[LEF,ROF]{\thepage}
```

or

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[RE,LO]{\includegraphics[width = 5.11cm, height=1.35cm]{example-image}}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
```

Then the image is in the inner footer and the page number is in the outer footer on both chapter pages and normal document pages.

The letters in the optional argument mean: `H` head, `F` foot, `E` even pages, `O` odd pages, `L` left, `R` right.

`\fancyhf[H]{...}` does the same as `\fancyhead{...}`.

Note that with page style `fancyplain` chapter pages uses the same page style as the other normal pages: page style `fancyplain`. If there should be a difference you can use eg.

```
\fancyhf[CH]{\fancyplain{plain}{other}}
```

Additional remark: It is recommended to use package `scrlayer-scrpage` for header and footer in KOMA-Script documents.

```
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ifoot*{\includegraphics[width = 5.11cm, height=1.35cm]{example-image}}
\ofoot*{\pagemark}
\chead[plain]{other}
```

Comment: @JoseLopez If my answer helps then maybe you can upvote it and if it solves your issue then you can accept it.